# Find and sort data in Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: excel, dbf

In my office, I have a dbf file that I can opened by Ms.Excel 2013

The dbx file is have a lot of rows that I want to filter based one column.

This is the File : [My Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-HrwpwjCFokZm1BZVE4RGlQRDQ/edit?usp=drive_web)

For example, I want to get the row that in POD_MN have value : EGYPT

The result will be placed in another table.

Thanks For the help...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save filtered results to another DBF table from MS Excel. To do this, you can use [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com/):

1.Install the app, open your DBF file with DBf Commander Pro.

2.Enter the following SQL query into the SQL Panel, select it and press F5 key:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE pod_mn='EGYPT' INTO TABLE another_table ORDER BY field1, field2
```

Don't forget to replace file name and field names with your values. ORDER BY clause is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable to analyze external data.
Use the option Insert > PivotTable > external data source.

Look at this tutorial:
https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-external-data-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b

Answer (score 0):

You can save filtered records to other DBF file with DBF Viewer 2000.
See this DBF Viewer help page: [Filtering records in DBF File](http://www.dbf2002.com/help/filtering_records_in_dbf.htm).